# Can I replace package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.HttpClient by any package if I don't it?

Tags: blazor, httpclient, blazor-webassembly

I use .Net6 ,I need add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Httpclient put I don't found it in NuGet Package Manager . is there way to found it ?
I need it to define GetJsonAsync I use this code

`return await _httpClient.GetjsonAsync<Empolyee[]>("api/Employees");`

I try install package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http but the message "HttpClient does not contain a definition for 'GetjsonAsync'.
I expect Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http replace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Httpclient or contain Httpclient

Comment: You shouldn't need any extra package, just `using System.Net.Http.Json;`

Comment: You have also a typo (maybe only in this question): GetJsonAsync should be with capital letter "J", not "GetjsonAsync".

Comment: Yes, I install package System.Net.Http.Json only ,and replace httpclient.GetjsonAsync with httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync

Answer (score 0):

Install the package "System.Net.Http.json "
and replace the code with this code
`return await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<Empolyee[]>("api/Employees")`